What is the relation between pcb trace width and number of layers
I need to design a PCB for RF Application.
The board contains jsut 4 sma connectors .They are Connected as shown below.

The frequency of operation is 20Ghz. Trace impedance should be 50 Ohm.Current 1A
Initially I decided to use 2layer board.Then I was told to use 4 layer board .The reason told to me is it will help to reduce the trace width.All the 4 are ground planes
May I know is there any relation between PCB trace width and number of layers.
Will the trace width reduces with number of layers.

Try calculating the trace dimensions for 50 ohms on a 2 layer board.

May I know how to calculate.Any suggestion for tools

It's not the number of layers, but the gap between signal and reference... 4-layer boards reduce that gap, but so do thinner PCBs

@Attie,May I know you have any mathematical equation for that.

@Confused What is the separation of the connectors? At 20 GHz you may need a PCB material meant for high frequencies. There are many web pages showing the equations for designing microstrip (2-layer structure) and stripline (embedded structure) transmission lines. Also, Saturn PCB Design has software where you can calculate various PCB parameters (impedance, DC resistance, ...).

SMA isn't really rated for 20GHz anyway. Are you sure about what you are doing?

@TimWilliams,May I know upto what frequency I can use SMA

Have you read the datasheet for the parts you have chosen?

Yes the bandwidth is given as 18Ghz

The number of layers doesn't make any difference in itself.
What matters for trace impedance on microstrip is, apart from PCB material, mainly the relation between trace width and spacing between trace and its reference plane, which is typically much smaller on a 4 layer board than a 2 layer board thus requiring thinner traces for the same impedance.

How spacing between trace and its reference plane decides the width of trace

@Confused I won't go into the math behind it all at this time. Go search "microstrip impedance calculator" in your favorite search engine and play around with different dimensions and see where it takes you.
